# PowerMock Doubts

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I have couple of doubts as I was going through the PowerMock documentation:
https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-powermock

Its mentioned to use a folder and place all Mock classes there:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(fullyQualifiedNames = "com.baeldung.powermockito.introduction.*")
```

My doubt is when the PowerMock will run, How will it identify which Mock is for which Real class, is how will it relate Util.java to MockUtil.java at runtime if Some class A has dependency to Util.java.

Other question is, just by placing     @PrepareForTest(fullyQualifiedNames = "com.baeldung.powermockito.introduction.*") will Real classes be replaced with Mock Classes at runtime when tests are executed.

Comment: That's not the powermock documentation, that's a random site's tutorial. Baeldung are consultants; you can apply to write articles for them for a tiny amount of money.

Comment: 1. question: by its "fully qulaified name" (if there are dups in class path, you might get other problems). 2. No, it only prepares; To "replace" you have to `PowerMockito.mockStatic(FooBar.class);`

Comment: 1. question: by its "fully qulaified name" (if there are dups in class path, you might get other problems)  -You mean, for any class under fullyQualifiedNames I just have to create a class with name prepending Mock and mock class is ready ?